# C stack memory usage breakdown in visual studio

Tags: c, memory, stack, heap-memory

I am developing a memory-critical embedded application in C and currently have the code running in visual studio on windows as easier for debugging.
In VS diagnostic tools I see that the total "Process Memory" is 3.4MB, but then when I take a snapshot using "Heap Profiling" it only shows the heap size, which is at 1.6MB.
I assume the difference between process and heap memory size is stack size, which it doesnt show.
Ideally I would like to see a breakdown of stack memory usage in the same way as it shows me which functions are using the heap space.   Is there a way to do this?
Or any other suggestions?
Many thanks.

Comment: The default stack for a process in Windows is always 1MiB.

Comment: The stack usage won't necessarily be the same, if the alignment requirements are different. This is a seperate issue from debugging, ans is perhpas best determined on the target, by using a stack fill to determine how much has been used.